# How to share snapshots and ami?

Tags: amazon-ebs

I have a snapshot of my ebs backed instance. I have registered an image of it. I wanted to share my snapshot with other account. Sharing was successful but when I tried to create an image from it, It showed an error (shown below)

```
"Invalid snapshot snap-xxxxxx" You are not authorized.
```

So, My questions are:

1. How can I make it successful ?
2. Do I need to create a volume by myself so that new image being created has a volume?
3. If I share an ami to other user, and other user runs an instance from it. who will be paying for this running instance ?
4. Any other ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly did not apply the launch permission that you thought you did.

Run the command

> ec2-describe-image-attribute ami-xxxxxxxx -l launchPermission ami-xxxxxxxx group all

and make sure that the AMI generated from the snapshot has launch permissions that allow the other account to launch it.